# Use Android ICU NumberFormat with only the JVM

Tags: java, android, jvm, currency, number-formatting

**Android** has the ICU library [NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/NumberFormat) which allows formatting currencies in different ways, in my specific case I need it as `ISOCURRENCYSTYLE`. This works great but only works on Android.

**Java** as its own implementation of [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with an instance builder called `getCurrencyInstance`, which internally uses a default currency style and doesn't allow to specify it.

Some of the differences are:

```
BE_FR | Android: 123,12 EUR |   Java: 123,12 €
BE_NL | Android: EUR 123,12 |   Java: € 123,12
BE_EN | Android: EUR 123.12 |   Java: €123,12
GE_GE | Android: EUR 123.12 |   Java: €123.12
FR_FR | Android: 123,12 EUR |   Java: 123,12 €
```

Is there a way to get the same Android output but only within the JVM, without using any external library?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to replace the prefix and the suffix of the `DecimalFormat` with the currency code:

```java
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test
{
    public static DecimalFormat geCurrencyFormat(Locale locale)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        String code = df.getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
        if(!df.getPositivePrefix().isEmpty())
        {
            df.setPositivePrefix(code + " ");
            df.setNegativePrefix(code + " -");
        }
        if(!df.getPositiveSuffix().isEmpty())
        {
            df.setPositiveSuffix(" " + code);
            df.setNegativeSuffix(" " + code);
        }
        return df;
    }

    public static void test(Locale locale)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = geCurrencyFormat(locale);
        System.out.println(df.format(123.12));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      test(new Locale("fr", "BE"));
      test(new Locale("nl", "BE"));
      test(new Locale("en", "GB"));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
123,12 EUR
EUR 123,12
GBP 123.12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But unfortunately, that doesn't output the same as Android: for example for `en_BE` Android outputs `EUR 123.12`, and your function outputs `123,12 EUR`.

Comment: @xatok English is not an official language in Belgium.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't the best example indeed, so for another case, let's say `nl_BE`:
Android outputs `EUR 123,12` and your snippet outputs `123,12 EUR`.

I'm looking for 1:1 consistency without the use of libraries, thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: @xatok My code outputs `EUR 123,12` for `nl_BE` with Java 17. It outputs `123,12 EUR` with older versions (I tested the code [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/)).

Comment: I gave you the bounty, although I cannot use it since I need it for Java 11. This is the closest correct answer I got, thank you :)

Comment: @xatok If you really need it for Java 11, the only way is to extract the information from ICU. You could write a small utility that uses ICU4J to export the currency position (before or after) to a .properties file for every locale. It would contain for example `nl_BE=B` and `fr_BE=A`. Then you can load the file and use it to put the currency at the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.  You can get the three-letter ISO 4217 codes using `Currency` and hand-craft things like:

```
Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE;
float amount = 123.1f;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
String formattedAmount = nf.format(amount) + " " + currency.getCurrencyCode());
```

However, Android is using ICU code to correctly order the value and units in the currency string.  This is not in the standard Java JDKs.

I understand you don't want to use a library, so this is out of scope of the required answer.  However, should you choose to use a library, take a look at ICU4J https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/.  It includes a `NumberFormat` with `ISOCURRENCYSTYLE` matching the Android behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I've checked the library and it works, but the size of the jar is 15MB, that's too much just for being able to use `ISOCURRENCYSTYLE` unfortunately.